# \url command worked fine before using \urldef

Tags: urls

Is there any way that `\urldef` can be overwritten by `\url`?
A link with a `%` sign or ~ sign used to work just fine with `\url` before I used `\urldef`. After `\urldef`, my `%` signs in the cited link serves as a line break.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\bibitem{BD}
\url{http://www.math.unl.edu/~bdeng1/Papers/DengHLCTmodel.pdf}, (Accessed on 24 August 2013)
\bibitem{AR13}  
\url{http://staff.science.uva.nl/~aroos/downloads/pdf_readers/syllabus.pdf}, (Accessed on 10 November 2013)

\end{document}
```

Can someone please check this? The first url works in a web browser whereas the second one does not. What could the problem possibly be? Will using `\urldef` fix this problem? If so, please suggest how? 
I would really appreciate any help.

Pdf output:
BD [31] http://www.math.unl.edu/~bdeng1/Papers/DengHLCTmodel.pdf, (Accessed
on 24 August 2013)
AR13 [32] http://staff.science.uva.nl/~aroos/downloads/pdf_readers/
syllabus.pdf, (Accessed on 10 November 2013)

Comment: could we have an mwe to observe this in effect, please?

Comment: How do I upload a snippet of my TeX code?

Comment: @Jivika edit your post. But please just just post a sniplet, that does not help much. Post something that can be copied to a file and compiled as is, without the need to add anything.

Comment: I don't see the problem in your example. It does work “correctly”. It doesn't even have a `\urldef`…

Comment: It produces an error when copied and pasted into a web browser.

Comment: @Manuel, what could one define in \urldef to remove the problems with special TeX symbols in the url?

Comment: I tried using `\urldef{myurl}\url{http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/tim/papers/2011/sluckin_Vito%20Volterra_2011.pdf}` in my preamble and then in the bibliography, `\myurl`. That is when all the TeX special symbols went haywire... Is there any way that I can go back to the standard `\url` settings?

Comment: @Jivika I still don't understad the relation with `\urldef` but it seems to me that, as the link is divided across lines, when you copy it, it adds a space between each par of lines. And that is a problem (which I don't know how to solve). As a workaround, you can use `hyperref` package which gets the links right since you can click on them.

Comment: Please optimize your MWEs. For example, remove packages that are not related to the problem. Also describe the problems in greater details.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, In the first sample, the `%` sign serves as a line break (after having defined `\urldef` last night. I removed `\urldef` and the links still do not work as it had before when using `\url`. The second sample yields a space when pasted into a web browser, despite using `\url`. Should I redefine `urldef`, and if so, what should it be?

Comment: @Jivika Where is `\urldef`? I still don't see it anywhere. Moreover, you still have many unnecessary packages. Again, read Heiko Oberdiek comment, post a document which shows the problem *and* explain how it doesn't work.

Comment: Will removing the .aux, .toc, .bbl files work?